# Powershell - how to assign a variable to the Directory im working in

Tags: powershell, batch-file

**DESCRIPTION :** 
I am trying to run a power shell script on a Build Release that ask a user to input their username and password , and then input the values into a .pubxml file. ( I am using Powershell 4)

**QUESTION :**
The .pubxml file is in the working directory of the build so i cant hardcode the full path i want to search the working directory for the .pubxml file in a loop or something similar, How can i find the `Get-Childitem` of the directory im working in?

**UPDATE**
 I am trying to get the working directory where my script is `$testFiles = Get-ChildItem "WorkingDirectoryofSCript".` I dont want to hardcode the path I want to find the path and then assign it to a variable `$testFiles`. Hope thats makes it clearer

I know how to do it in batch script (probably not the best solution but works)

```
for %%* in (.) do set CurrentDirName=%%~nx*
echo CurrentDirName: %CurrentDirName%

If not "%CurrentDirName%" == "somefolder" (
echo "The current dir name is not somefolder"
cd..
Pause
Goto CheckDirName

)
```

I want to do something similar in power shell.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Question is a bit unclear, are you perhaps looking for `$PWD`?

Comment: Updated my question hope its clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the version of PowerShell you're using you can use the following commands:

PowerShell 3 and higher

```
$PSScriptRoot
```

PowerShell 2

```
$currentDirectory = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

This will return the directory that the script is ran in.

Comment: So i can just assign the `$testFiles = $PSScriptRoot` and then go `Get-ChildItem $testFiles`?

Comment: Yeah. That will give you the directory that the script is located in. At that point you can use Get-ChildItem.